# Layout tab widget at bottom of screen

Tags: android-layout, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

How can I layout my tab widget at the bottom of the screen? It shows right below the action bar on the top. I tried align parent bottom and layout gravity bottom but those aren't working.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```